# How can I access the model objects after annotating a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have a QuerySet where I annotate the datefield and that works just fine. see my code below.

```
tenderSet = userTenders.annotate(d_assigned=TruncDay('date_assigned')).values('d_assigned').annotate(c=Count('id')).values('d_assigned', 'c').order_by("-d_assigned")
```

And this is the output. [image]

My problem is that I want to be able to click on the links in the image and see the actual objects. For example, if click on the link that says "2 tenders" in the image above, I would like to have access to the "tender" objects associated with that annotation. But unfortunately because my annotation above returns a QuerySet of "dictionaries" i am unable to access the model objects. I need to know if there is a way to keep the look of the listView above and still be able to access the annotated tender objects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have access to all the objects right?

Then you have to pass some parameters to the page so you can do that exact annotation there.

For your example you can pass the date and filter it in your view.

It would be something like this:

Your page url: `something.com/pagename/?date=some-date`

or: `something.com/year/month/day/`

then in your view you can filter the queryset for that date:

```
tenderSet = userTenders.filter(date=<The Date You Got from URL>)
```

Now you'll have all the objects for that date so you can repeat the annotations or what ever you want.

Basically whenever you need a page for some filters you made, you need to get the filtering parameters from page url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the dates are saved in the database. Multiple tender objects can have the same date hence the annotation on the datefield.

Comment: Don't you need the all the objects for that specific date? Then you'll have a list of all the objects for the date you filtered the data with. If you want one specific objects, then you have to pass one or more parameters to the page to get that object too. And if you need to pass some parameters about objects, then add the values you need to your `values`.